# Odd behavior of GLSL switch statement

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to draw a cube with a different texture on each side. I pass Textnum parameter containing the number of the texture to use through my vertex shader to my fragment shader, then use a switch statement to choose appropriate sampler2D based on its value:

```
#version 150

in float Shade;
in vec2 Textcoord;
in uint Textnum;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
uniform sampler2D tex3;
uniform sampler2D tex4;
uniform sampler2D tex5;

void main()
{
    vec4 textColor;
    switch(Textnum)
    {
        case 0u: textColor = texture(tex0, Textcoord); break;
        case 1u: textColor = texture(tex1, Textcoord); break;
        case 2u: textColor = texture(tex2, Textcoord); break;
        case 3u: textColor = texture(tex3, Textcoord); break;
        case 4u: textColor = texture(tex4, Textcoord); break;
        case 5u: textColor = texture(tex5, Textcoord); break;
    }
    outColor = textColor * vec4(Shade, Shade, Shade, 1);
}
```

With this code, the cube is not being rendered at all. The textures are loaded properly, because when I do:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 textColor; 
    textColor = texture(tex0, Textcoord);
    outColor = textColor * vec4(Shade, Shade, Shade, 1);
}
```

I see a cube with the same texture on each side. I tried this with all of the samplers, each time getting the expected result. What's interesting is when I do:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 textColor;
    switch(Textnum)
    {
        case 0u: textColor = texture(tex0, Textcoord); break;
        case 1u: textColor = texture(tex1, Textcoord); break;
        case 2u: textColor = texture(tex2, Textcoord); break;
        case 3u: textColor = texture(tex3, Textcoord); break;
        case 4u: textColor = texture(tex4, Textcoord); break;
        case 5u: textColor = texture(tex5, Textcoord); break;
    }
    textColor = texture(tex0, Textcoord);
    outColor = textColor * vec4(Shade, Shade, Shade, 1);
}
```

I still see no cube, even when the instruction after the switch statement should overwrite its effects. What's wrong with my code?

EDIT: So apparently this is not the end yet, because if I do this (which should be correct on the grounds of the Wikipedia article):

```
void main()
{
    vec4 textColor;
    vec4 textColor0 = texture(tex0, Textcoord);
    vec4 textColor1 = texture(tex1, Textcoord);
    vec4 textColor2 = texture(tex2, Textcoord);
    vec4 textColor3 = texture(tex3, Textcoord);
    vec4 textColor4 = texture(tex4, Textcoord);
    vec4 textColor5 = texture(tex5, Textcoord);
    switch(Textnum)
    {
        case 0u: textColor = textColor0; break;
        case 1u: textColor = textColor1; break;
        case 2u: textColor = textColor2; break;
        case 3u: textColor = textColor3; break;
        case 4u: textColor = textColor4; break;
        case 5u: textColor = textColor5; break;
    }
    outColor = textColor * vec4(Shade, Shade, Shade, 1);
}
```

The cube is still not being rendered at all. This doesn't work as well:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 textColor[6];
    textColor[0] = texture(tex0, Textcoord);
    textColor[1] = texture(tex1, Textcoord);
    textColor[2] = texture(tex2, Textcoord);
    textColor[3] = texture(tex3, Textcoord);
    textColor[4] = texture(tex4, Textcoord);
    textColor[5] = texture(tex5, Textcoord);
    outColor = textColor[Textnum] * vec4(Shade, Shade, Shade, 1);
}
```

EDIT2: Here is the complete example for anyone interested: http://pastebin.com/R2scC0ZZ

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't see any glsl compile-error in the last code?  It might hide in the  pile of output.

Comment: No, I check for compile errors and my program didn't report anything suspicious.

Comment: I will do a guess.   (I am a beginner.)  Try add "default:" in the switch.

Comment: I tried doing that as well and still got the same result. No cube is being rendered.

Comment: Another guess : are you sure nothing was rendered?  It might be black.  Try changing background color (my favorite is 1 0 1) may help sometimes.

Comment: Nothing was rendered, when I set background color to red all I see is red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texture lookups in glsl have to be in uniform control flow. In your case the flow is non-uniform since it depends on a attribute. In this case no automatic gradients are calculated and everything that depends on gradients (mipmaps, anisotropic filtering) will not work.

[This link](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control) gives a more detailed explanation about this face.

Edit: Now that I saw the complete code, it is rather clear why it is not working. The shader simply doesn't link with the following error message:

```
0(4) : error C5215: Integer varying TextNum must be flat
```

This message tells you exactly what is the problem here: Integer varyings cannot be interpolated between shader stages, thus they have to be defined with flat interpolation. Obviously you didn't check for linker errors. Since the program did not link, every call to `glUseProgram` produces a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` because the program wasn't valid and nothing was drawn. Replacing the attribute definition with:

```
flat out uint Textnum;
```

and

```
flat in uint Textnum;
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that there is no way to get a cube with different texture on each side without rendering each side separately?

Comment: @Piotr Olszewski  That link contains what you want.  It is possible.  See the paragraph around "only add it based on the condition".  It is also new for me, +1 both of you. :)

Comment: @PiotrOlszewski: You can always use a 2D array texture with 6 layers and index the layer through an attribute (it's just another texture coordinate).

Comment: @datenwolf Yeah, that works, but I'd really like to get down to the cause of the behavior I observed. I know that the first snippets of code failed because they weren't in uniform control flow, but I see no reason for the ones after the edit to behave as they do.

Comment: Have you checked whether `Textnum` contains the correct value? The only other option I see is that you create a complete and minimal example with which we can test with.

Comment: @BDL Here it is: http://pastebin.com/R2scC0ZZ. I've just noticed something crucial: `glUseProgram` fails with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` if I use `TextNum` anywhere in the shader code. However, if I don't use it, the shader compiler optimizes it away and loading the attribute fails with `GL_INVALID_VALUE` .

Comment: It's not a big surprise it doesn't work. You are getting glsl linker errors. See update of answer.

Comment: @BDL Thank you very much again. Sorry for late reply, but I must have somehow missed notification about this comment. On a side note, I feel incredibly stupid for having no idea that `glLinkProgram` can fail and has its own log. I guess I should read documentation more thoroughly in the future.